# Apache ModRewrite Issues .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to create a mod rewrite that will change the following:

https://example.com/app/landing to https://example.com?keyword=landing
and
https://example.com/app/adwords to https://example.com?keyword=adwords

However, I have not been able to do so.
I am using codeiginter which already requires a few rules to be in place to prevent index.php? to be in the URL, therfore I am unsure as to whether or not this is creating my problem.

Here is the current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

Try 1:
RewriteRule landing https://example.com/?keyword=landing [R]

Try 2:
RewriteRule ^landing?/ https://example.com/?keyword=landing [R]

Try 3:
RewriteRule ^landing?/ https://example.com/?keyword=landing [R]

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?